# Redux connect multiple components with same action

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have multiple components (screens) connected like this:

```
import { setNavigationHeader } from './actions';

const MyScreen = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setNavigationHeader('MyScreen title');
  });

  ...
}

const mdtp = {
  setNavigationHeader
}

export default connect(null, mdtp)(MyScreen);
```

Is there any way to "inject" this into the component so I can reuse it for multiple components? Maybe with a HOC?

I'm pretty new to React so I don't know what would be the best course of action here.

Also, I would need to be able add more actions to the mapDispatchToProps or to add a mapStateToProps if I want.

Comment: you can use same actions in multiple components without any issue.

Comment: Yeah I know, I was just looking for a way to avoid repeating that on all components

Comment: then go with HOC for better resuability

Answer (score 0):

The [connect function](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect-returns) actually returns a **HOC**, you just need to create it once and reuse it inside your screen components

```
// navigation.utils.js
import { setNavigationHeader } from './actions';
export const connectScreen = connect(null, {setNavigationHeader});


// MyScreen.js
import { connectScreen } from './navitation.utils'
const MyScreen = ...
export default connectScreen(MyScreen);

// MyScreen2.js
import { connectScreen } from './navitation.utils'
const MyScreen2 = ...
export default connectScreen(MyScreen2);
```